# Is it safe to store server paths on a react client for a session

Tags: javascript, reactjs, security, client

We are working on an application, where a react or angular client interacts with a server using apis.In a Few operations we read write files from dynamic locations of the file system. We therefore need to specify to the server the file name and the path of the file to read/write. My worry is, is this a secure and safe thing to do? Is this a normal practice / good design ?

Note : The application does not allow entering paths manually and the server also accepts paths within a sandbox.

So says a user goes through the pain of using browser console and sees a server path as /home/username/….. is that a matter of concern ? The user of the software is mostly the server owner or coworker of the owner.

The relevant aspect of the design has been explained above.Please provide some insights into the security concerns of this design.